# Infinite vertical world

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I am created two bodies in Box2d, they are: Player and Platform;

I wanted to create game like Doodle Jump, but I don't know how to create "infinite world with generating platforms";

There is my code where I am creating Array:

```
buckets = new Array<Bucket>();

for(int i=1;i<BUCKET_COUNT;i++){
    buckets.add(new Bucket(W/2,BUCKET_MARGIN*i, world));
}
```

And this code where I am "Trying" to change position of each platform when camera position is change:

```
for(Bucket bucket : buckets){
        if(cam.position.y - (cam.viewportHeight/2) > bucket.getBody().getPosition().y + 22/PPM){
            bucket.repos(W/2,bucket.getBody().getPosition().y + BUCKET_MARGIN);
        }
    }
```

It works! **But** it changes last platform position to very far bottom:

Comment: Games of this type only simulate infinity. Just move all your platforms down and keep your character on the same vertical position

Comment: you dont have to use box2d for a doodle jump clone, actually it would only make it more complex with no reason. Fortunately for you, there's already a doodle jump clone made with libgdx complete with source code, actually made by the libgdx core contributors, its called Super Jumper https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper

Answer (score 2):

Regarding **how to create an infinite world?**

Use the world instance *shift origin* method. In the Box2D 2.3.2 C++ library code, this is the `b2World::ShiftOrigin(const b2Vec2& newOrigin)` method. Here's an excerpt of this method's declaration along with its documentation:

```
/// Shift the world origin. Useful for large worlds.
/// The body shift formula is: position -= newOrigin
/// @param newOrigin the new origin with respect to the old origin
void ShiftOrigin(const b2Vec2& newOrigin);
```

In Java, you should be able to find a similar interface method.

With *shift origin* you keep the viewport to the physics world centered on (or near) the physical world origin (of 0, 0). This is basically the practical means of accomplishing what Yevhen Danchenko suggested in the comments.

A reason for using this is that the implementation of floating-point arithmetic which Box2D relies on, is itself not infinitely wide ranging nor infinitely accurate. So shifting things helps keep things closer to the origin where the floating-point values are more accurate and keeps things from going off the range of practically usable values assuming that you'll only ever be showing a limited range of x and y values.